# WinForms UI-Thread processing UI-Events when blocked by SyncLock-Statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, devexpress

We have a WinForms application that is mostly written in Visual Basic .NET and .NET 4.7 and uses DevExpress-WinForms Controls.
In this application we of course have a UI-Thread and also several background threads (started by using `Task.Run()`, `myTask.Start()`, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` or a combination of all).
We know that this is in no way optimal but some of the code is 20+ years old and not easy to rewrite.

Now all the background threads try to get data from an SQL Server database.
We keep track of the connections we create and keep them in a kind of pool (basically just a Dictionary<int, Connection> where the key is the thread-id and the value is the actual connection object).
For a thread to get or create a connection we therefore implemented Locking via `SyncLock _connectionLock` so that only one thread can get or create a connection at a time.
Only the creation and opening of the connection is done within the `SyncLock`, nothing more.

When all these threads are started, at some point one of our `DevExpress.XTraTreeList.TreeList`-Controls raises a `CustomDrawNodeCells`-Event that causes the UI-Thread to also try and access the database. Since we are not using async/await it has to synchronously block until it can acquire the _connectionLock that I mentioned earlier.

While the UI-Thread is waiting to acquire the lock I can see that the method containing the `SyncLock`-Statement is the last frame on the CallStack.
Once one of the many background threads finishes, this causes the finishing thread to `Invoke` back into the UI-Thread and call `TreeList.Refresh()` at some point.

The UI-Thread now throws an exception because it is trying to recursively reenter a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` that it already has (not the lock that I mentioned before).
At the time when the exception is thrown, the CallStack of the UI-Thread looks like "something somehow managed to put a new frame on top of the Method that is waiting to acquire the connection lock".
(Sorry but I really cannot think of a better way to describe it)

As I said, before, when I looked at the CallStack of the UI-Thread, the method that is waiting to acquire the connection lock is the top most method. Now when the exception is thrown, I can still see the CallStack up until this method. But now on top of this method I can also see a "Managed to Native Transistion" followed by a "Native to Managed Transition" that is then followed by yet another `TreeList.CustomDrawNodeCells`-Event (maybe raised by the `TreeList.Refresh()`?).

I don't understand how "work" can be "queued" and actually be executed by one thread (the UI-Thread in particular) while it should be blocking until it receives the lock to get a connection to the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
Just to be clear:
The question is not really related to fixing this issue but rather to understand what is happening.
Essentially my only question is, how and why does the CallStack of the UI-Thread show frames on top of another frame that should be blocking the thread and even execute these "new" frames?

The CallStack of the UI-Thread looks basically like this:

```
at MyProject.OnCustomDrawNodeCells
at TreeList.CustomDrawNodeCells
[Native to managed transition]
[Managed to native transition]
at DatabaseAccess.GetConnection (this should block until the thread can acquire the lock)
at MyProject.OnCustomDrawNodeCells
at TreeList.CustomDrawNodeCells
```

Comment: By my knowledge there is already connection pooling implemented for much of the default Sql sdks, however, this is not your question. In the case you describe, i'd say you offload the database call to another thread and when finished, you use control.invoke to use the ui thread to update the controls. This question pretty much descibes it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the?rq=2 However, I might be missing your point considering the level of detail in your question and the ease of this solution :P

Comment: We are already doing that with all the background threads but since our application was developed 20+ years ago and much of the original code is still in place, pretty much nothing is asynchronous and very heavily bound to the UI directly. Honestly I am not quite sure what the intention behind the "custom" connection pooling was but it's what we currently use anyway. My question is pretty much "only" why I see this weird behavior on the CallStack of the UI-Thread.

Comment: It looks to me like what you're describing is something like this: worker thread takes lock to do DB work - UI thread waits on lock to do DB work - worker thread finishes with DB work and before UI thread has released, tries to call into the UI thread to do a UI update.  If so, I think the errors are stopping a deadlock, and you need to figure out how to re-arrange the locking.  It might involve having the worker thread push something into a work queue that the UI thread can check explicitly.  There are synchronized collections that may help.

Comment: Or alternatively, it's a bad idea to have the UI thread block, so don't do that.  Push anything that it might want to block on off into another thread so that the UI thread is always available to do UI things.

Comment: I just updated the question. I appreciate the suggestions on how to fix the issue, but this is not really what this question is about. Sorry for being a little unclear.